# How does it make sense that the force of friction is equal to the force applied if a object is in constant motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

In order for a object to be in motion one force must overcome the other and not be at an equilibrium. How is it possible that when a object is moving at a constant speed that the force of friction equals the force applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it's not accelerating if the net force is zero. So if it's moving, it has a constant velocity.

Comment: But isn't friction a force that must be overcome in order for the object to move?

Comment: You are probably confusing [static friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction) with [kinetic friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Kinetic_friction). If it's moving, static friction is not a factor, but kinetic friction is (an vice versa).